How to paste multi-line text to a PHPdoc comment without spoiling it?
I have a problem illustrated below:


VSCode is ultimately just a text editor. It pastes the text exactly as you copied it. It would need to pass the pasted text to the extension that handles PHP / formatting and somehow know it should take care of the newlines within a comment. You can visit the VSCode issue tracker or issue tracker for the extension you're using and create a feature request (check if one exists for this first!).

For those who are insisting that this is about VSCode but not PHP, remember that VS Code is, for many people, their IDE - and with the right plugins, it's a pretty fully functional one.  It's not unreasonable to expect that your IDE, knowing the language, will handle contextual pasting properly.  Insisting that it's just a text editor is ignoring the existence of the plugins that make it a code editor (it's in the name!).  This question is specific to editing PHP, so it's about PHP.

The only workaround I have found so far is using multi-line cursor:

But the issue here is that you should know ahead of time the exact amount of required lines. It is also almost unusable in case of lines counted by tens.

Try PHPStorm, it's pricy but i'll do the job. You can test trial verions if it works for you.

You can paste it and then convert it into a multiline comment. Select the multiline text and then press these keys according to your operating system.
Windows: Shift+Alt+A
Linux: Shift+Ctrl+A
MacOS: shift+option+A
